# Force StreamBuilder to reload on gesture detection

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I got a `StreamBuilder` which is fetching data using an http request. After a certain time it times out and shows a reload widget. Now I want the `StreamBuilder`to reload and fetch the data again when a gesture tap is detected on the widget.
Currently my `StreamBuilder` uses a `GestureDetector` to detect the tap:

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Stream.fromFuture(makeHttpRequest).timeout(
          const Duration(seconds: 5),
          onTimeout: (sink) {
            sink.addError(TimeoutException('Timeout'));
            sink.close();
          },
        ),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<models.Tutorial>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            if (snapshot.error is TimeoutException) {
              return GestureDetector(
                  child: const Center(
                    child: IconTextPair(
                      iconPath: "assets/reload.svg",
                      text: "Keine Verbindung zum Server",
                      direction: Axis.vertical,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () => setState(() {}));
            }
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // display data
          }
          return LoadingAnimationWidget.fourRotatingDots(
              color: const Color(0xFF465770), size: 45);
        });
```

The tap on the widget is detected but the `StreamBuilder` won't reload. How do I force the `StreamBuilder` to reload and fetch the data again? The `StreamBuilder` is build during `initState`.

Comment: check how [FooSearch2](https://gist.github.com/pskink/31f7763986ea67bac2d1af0926685c11#file-foo_search-dart-L15) reloads `StreamBuilder` each time you type something in edit text, do similar thing when gesture callback is called

Comment: This doesn't seem to work since asyncMap wants a FutureOr function but I got a Future function to fetch the data

Comment: yes it works, `FutureOr<T>` accepts either `Future<T>` or `T` objects - see how `_getAPI` is used in `asyncMap` method

Comment: I managed to get it compile but for some reason no reload is happening... It should call `controller.add` when the gesture gets recognized but nothing happens... The gesture is recognized correctly...

Comment: to be sure, just for testing, add `ElevatedButton` with `onPressed: () => controller.add(anything)` and add some `print` inside the function passed to `asyncMap` method

Comment: Same thing happens using the `ElevatedButton`. The gesture is detected but the function won't get executed. But for some reason the stream doesn't seem to work in any way using the controller and the data stream...

Comment: how do you create s stream passed to `StreamBuilder` and what is your `onPressed` callback?

Comment: `dataStream = controller.stream.asyncMap((_) => HttpRequest.getTutorialList());` this is how the `dataStream` is created which gets parsed to the `StreamBuilder`. My `ElevatedButton` callback looks like this: `ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {controller.add;}, child: Text("R"))`

Comment: The `dataStream` gets parsed using a timeout like shown above which times out after 30 secs

Comment: I tried to add a String `"reload"` which doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: Yes I tried `controller.add("reload")`

Comment: Didn't work either.
I think the problem is that the Future function which is parsed to the stream of the controller never gets called, even when building the StreamBuilder for the first time.

Comment: Your `FooRefresh` seems to work just fine... I can't parse my function which is fetching the data because `The argument type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>> Function(dynamic)'.`

Comment: It seems like nothing happened because I didn't parse a initialData value... Now everything just works fine. Thanks for your help!